# 'Cannot read property 'apps' of undefined' in nuxtJs/ firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nuxt.js

I have tried to integrate firebase with Nuxt Js and i am getting this error

[image]

As per documentation first I have installed firebase with help of "npm install firebase" and then i have installed "npm install @nuxtjs/firebase" and third i have integrated my firebase config in **modules** in **nuxt.config.js**

[image]

so whats the solution to solve the above error?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Which version of firebase are you using?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which version of @nuxtjs/firebase you are using, because this package @nuxtjs/firebase is not compatible with firebase version 9+ supporting tree-shaking.

So you need to downgrade you package to firebase version 8 and prior.

For more information, please check the authors github issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the new [Modular SDK v9.0.1](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#add-sdk-and-initialize) you might get the above error as it does not use `firebase.` namespace now,
Try using `getApps()` instead of `firebase.apps`.

```
import { initializeApp, getApps } from "firebase/app" 
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore"
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth" 
const firebaseConfig = {...} 
if (!getApps().length) {
 //.... 
} 
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig) 
const db = getFirestore(app) 
const auth = getAuth(app) export {db, auth}
```

Answer (score 0):

I banged my head against this problem for a while - I was trying to use the Realtime Database in a dynamic page and getting the same error. I finally went back to [this issue on the firebase module repo](https://github.com/nuxt-community/firebase-module/issues/89). Basically I had to do two things:

1. use the `async asyncData` method instead of just defining `data` properties; and
2. use both the `app` and `params` variables.

So instead of this:

```js
export default {
  data: () => ({
    items: []
  )},
  async fetch ({ params }) {
    const ref = this.$fire.database.ref(`foo/${params.slug}`)
    const data = (await ref.once('value')).val()
    this.items = data
  }
}
```

I had to do this:

```js
export default {
  async asyncData ({ app, params }) {
    const ref = app.$fire.database.ref(`foo/${params.slug}`)
    const data = (await ref.once('value')).val()
    return { items: data }
  }
}
```